# Python multiple search based on enabled or not

Tags: python, if-statement

Everyone, hello!

I'm currently trying to find several strings of text in telnet, from the Telnetlib (https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) in Python 2.7.

So far, the snippet I'm using that works great is:

```
 while True:
    r = tn.read_some()
    if any(x in r for x in [string1, string2]):
        action
```

The issue I'm facing is that I have several more strings (roughly 3 or so in total). Depending if they are enabled I would like to include them into the if function.

The enabling/disabling is set in ConfigParser in a config.ini file named string1_enable = yes/no

The longest route (and the only one I can think of right now is)

```
if string1_enable == "yes" and string2_enable == "no" and string3_enable "no":
    s1 = (x in r for x in [string1])
if string1_enable == "no" and string2_enable == "yes" and string3_enable "no":
    s2 = (x in r for x in [string2])
```

This would of course be a disaster to look at, impossibly long to go through and I wouldn't even know how to properly implement it....
Thus, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a list based on the config:

```
strings = []
if string1_enable == "yes":
    strings.append(string1)
if string2_enable == "yes":
    strings.append(string2)
if string3_enable == "yes":
    strings.append(string3)

while True:
   r = tn.read_some()
   if any(x in r for x in strings):
       action
```